# Get last table tr and div of displayed window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two HTML files.

First:

```
<table>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Second:

```
<div=container>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

`table` and `container` have more vertical size than the window. How can I get the current last tr(div) content displayed in the window?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand this, could you rephrase your question?

Comment: I think he wants to find the last `tr` or `div` that's visible in the current window (excluding those that you'd need to scroll down to see).

Comment: he wants to find out the last visible row above the fold

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simple jQuery plugin [here](http://upshots.org/javascript/jquery-test-if-element-is-in-viewport-visible-on-screen) that checks if an object is visible on screen. You could cycle through each of the `div` or `tr` elements in reverse order, using that code to check if it's inside the current window, until you find the one that *is* visible on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can use css3 selectors, so the following should work:

```
$("table > tr:last-of-type")
```

Similarly for the div:

```
$("div#container > div:last-of-type")
```

This will get the last element of type within the first element specified in the selector. If you actually want what is above the fold, this is not the solution